# change ownership of all files from root to user

Tags: chown, ownership

i'm new to Ubuntu and was wondering if there is a way to remove the ownership of all files and scripts from root to user even if i have to re-install Ubuntu?
i do know about the command 'chown -v username foldername', although it doesn't work on all files.

Comment: If you take away root ownership of some files, Ubuntu will stop working. Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Really bad things will happen if you do this.

Answer (score 21):

Just go to the directory you want to change:

```
cd /opt/lampp/htdocs
```

and change the permission using the `chown` command:

```
sudo chown userName -R codeigniter
```

Where `userName` is the username and `codeigniter` is the folder's name.

Comment: @spasSpasov: Could you please review my [edits](http://askubuntu.com/posts/874432/revisions) and also review the [editing help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) to improve the readability of your own edits in the future... **;-)**

Comment: @Fabby Yes of course, I will.

Comment: Sure.But the Answer will not be helpfull for new users.

Answer (score 10):

When you do an install you have several directories.  Everything in `/home/user/` can be changed to your `user`.  If you `chown` the others your system will break.  And when you chown you need to make sure you `chown` to the `user` and NOT just some name you choose.  It will be the same name as the folder under `/home/`. Do not change either permissions or ownership of anything but files under `/home/user/`.

```
sudo chown -v -R user:user /home/user/
```

The command will change the user and the group to the same at the same time.

Comment: And all files become executable permissions? sorry, that's a -1

Answer (score 4):

The below is for individual file:

```
sudo chown user:user filename
```

For an entire directory it will be:

```
sudo chown user:user dirName
```

For recursive (i.e files and folders inside a folder):

```
sudo chown -R user:user dirName
```

Note: `user` is, if you do `pwd` under any Documents, you will see the path: `/home/jhon/Documents`. Here user is `jhon`.