# NFS Share Permissions between WDMyCloud / RaspberryPi with OwnCloud

Tags: server, permissions, nfs, ownership, owncloud-server

Looking for some assistance in setting up an NFS share between WDMyCloud (NFS Server) and RaspberryPi (NFS Client).

I have set up the share successfully using the below config but having some difficulty in setting up the correct permissions for OwnCloud to access the files.

**WDMyCloud (NFS Server)**

/etc/exports

```
# Use nobody user (uid 65534) for nfs guest.  This is restricted from private
# shares by ACLs.
#
/nfs/owncloud 192.168.0.25(rw,all_squash,sync,no_subtree_check,insecure,crossmnt,anonuid=33,anongid=33)
```

grep 33 /etc/passwd

```
www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/bin/sh
```

grep 33 /etc/group

```
www-data:x:33:root,nobody,daapd
```

**Raspberry Pi (NFS Client)**

/etc/fstab

```
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
/dev/mmcblk0p1  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2
/dev/mmcblk0p2  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
# a swapfile is not a swap partition, no line here
#   use  dphys-swapfile swap[on|off]  for that
192.168.0.30:/nfs/owncloud  /owncloud   nfs nouser,atime,auto,rw,dev,exec,suid 0 0
```

Mounts successfully

```
raspberrypi ~ # df -h
Filesystem                  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root                    15G  1.8G   13G  13% /
devtmpfs                    237M     0  237M   0% /dev
tmpfs                       242M  8.5M  233M   4% /run
tmpfs                       242M     0  242M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mmcblk0p1               63M   21M   43M  33% /boot
192.168.0.30:/nfs/owncloud  3.6T  151G  3.4T   5% /owncloud
```

But listing the directory, it shows different user/group:

```
raspberrypi ~ # ls -lAh /owncloud/
total 172K
drwxr-xr-x 2 nobody pi 4.0K Oct 17 22:01 files_external
-rw-r--r-- 1 nobody pi  284 Oct 17 21:37 .htaccess
-rw-r--r-- 1 nobody pi  145 Oct 17 22:01 htaccesstest.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 nobody pi    0 Oct 17 22:01 index.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 nobody pi 156K Oct 17 22:01 owncloud.db
-rw-r--r-- 1 nobody pi    0 Oct 17 22:01 owncloud.log
```

I'm not even carrying out this as the user 'pi' so not sure why this group is being used:

```
raspberrypi ~ # whoami
root
```

I have attempted a restart of the "nfs-kernel-server" service on the server-side alongside an `exportfs -a` with no luck.

What I'm trying to achieve is for the file/directory ownership to be "www-data" for both user and group.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers,

**UPDATE:**

Just to add, the UUID for `www-data` on the Raspberry Pi is also 33:

```
raspberrypi ~ # grep 33 /etc/passwd
www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/usr/sbin/nologin
raspberrypi ~ # grep 33 /etc/group
www-data:x:33:www-data
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [change ownership of all files from root to user](http://askubuntu.com/questions/623864/change-ownership-of-all-files-from-root-to-user)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate as I'm not sure if updating permissions on server-side will affect the running on the share on the WDMyCloud (server) side.

Comment: https://community.wd.com/t/folder-permissions/91413

Comment: Which NFS version are you using? Maybe [serverfault.com/questions/520276/nfs-user-mapping](http://serverfault.com/questions/520276/nfs-user-mapping) may help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that all the files in the NFS mount need to be owned by the webserver user. Otherwise you will run into problems. The easiest is if you mount it via smbclient as the webserver user and do a symlink of the data directory. By the way. It is recommended to use Nextcloud instead of ownCloud because it contains important security fixes. Nextcloud also has a feature to access smb shares directly. This is very easy.